# Blazor server side - redirecting if unauthenticated before the page starts loading

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Might be trying to solve this the wrong way, but here's the situation.

I have a component designed to redirect to login if the user trying to access it isn't authenticated, and display not found if they aren't authorized for the page requested.

```
<AuthorizeViewWithPermissions RequiredPermission="RequiredPermission">
    <Authorized>
        @ChildContent
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthenticated>
        <LoginRedirect />
    </NotAuthenticated>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <NotFoundRedirect />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeViewWithPermissions>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Permissions RequiredPermission { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

    }
}
```

LoginRedirect is this:

```
    public class LoginRedirect : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject] protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login", true);
        }
    }
```

internals of AuthorizeViewWithPermissions:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Largely borrowed from the original AuthorizeView, but cut up a bit to use custom permissions and cut out a lot of stuff that isn't needed.
    /// </summary>
    public class AuthorizeViewWithPermissions : ComponentBase
    {
        private AuthenticationState _currentAuthenticationState;

        private bool _isAuthorized;

        private bool _isAuthenticated;

        /// <summary>
        /// The permission type required to display the content
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public Permissions RequiredPermission { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The content that will be displayed if the user is authorized.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment<AuthenticationState> ChildContent { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The content that will be displayed if the user is not authorized.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment<AuthenticationState> NotAuthorized { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The content that will be displayed if the user is not authenticated.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment<AuthenticationState> NotAuthenticated { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The content that will be displayed if the user is authorized.
        /// If you specify a value for this parameter, do not also specify a value for <see cref="ChildContent"/>.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment<AuthenticationState> Authorized { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The content that will be displayed while asynchronous authorization is in progress.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment Authorizing { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The resource to which access is being controlled.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter] public object Resource { get; set; }

        [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationState { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            // We're using the same sequence number for each of the content items here
            // so that we can update existing instances if they are the same shape
            if (_currentAuthenticationState == null)
            {
                builder.AddContent(0, Authorizing);
            }
            else if (_isAuthorized)
            {
                var authorized = Authorized ?? ChildContent;
                builder.AddContent(0, authorized?.Invoke(_currentAuthenticationState));
            }
            else if (!_isAuthenticated)
            {
                builder.AddContent(0, NotAuthenticated?.Invoke(_currentAuthenticationState));
            }
            else
            {
                builder.AddContent(0, NotAuthorized?.Invoke(_currentAuthenticationState));
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            // We allow 'ChildContent' for convenience in basic cases, and 'Authorized' for symmetry
            // with 'NotAuthorized' in other cases. Besides naming, they are equivalent. To avoid
            // confusion, explicitly prevent the case where both are supplied.
            if (ChildContent != null && Authorized != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Do not specify both '{nameof(Authorized)}' and '{nameof(ChildContent)}'.");
            }

            if (AuthenticationState == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Authorization requires a cascading parameter of type Task<{nameof(AuthenticationState)}>. Consider using {typeof(CascadingAuthenticationState).Name} to supply this.");
            }

            // First render in pending state
            // If the task has already completed, this render will be skipped
            _currentAuthenticationState = null;

            // Then render in completed state
            // Importantly, we *don't* call StateHasChanged between the following async steps,
            // otherwise we'd display an incorrect UI state while waiting for IsAuthorizedAsync
            _currentAuthenticationState = await AuthenticationState;
            SetAuthorizedAndAuthenticated(_currentAuthenticationState.User);
        }

        private void SetAuthorizedAndAuthenticated(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            var userWithData = SessionHelper.GetCurrentUser(user);

            _isAuthenticated = userWithData != null;
            _isAuthorized = userWithData?.Permissions.Any(p => p == RequiredPermission || p == Permissions.SuperAdmin) ?? false;
        }
    }
```

The authentication and authorization checks are working perfectly fine, but the issue is that the page OnInitializedAsync or OnParametersSetAsync fire before the LoginRedirect OnInitialized.

I'm kicking off my calls for data (to an API, that uses a token stored on the logged in user's data) in OnInitializedAsync which results in it attempting to load the data (with no auth token) instead of just redirecting.  If I comment out the data call the redirect works as expected without issue, so it's just a timing/sequence of events issue.

Is there a solution to this? Should I just be changing my api client code to silently fail instead of throwing an unauthorized exception if the auth token is missing?

This is also my app.razor component:

```
CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginRedirect />
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Checking authorization...</p>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>These aren't the droids you're looking for.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: This might be related, but for a more specific case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882574/how-can-i-prevent-or-globally-react-to-uncaught-accesstokennotavailableexception

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if you have a user before the call to the api:

```cs
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

...

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authenticationstateprovider-service)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to put that same code on every page, that's the whole reason for building the components already in place.

Comment: You can inject an `AuthenticationStateProvider` where evever you need to use it

Comment: Yes, but having to duplicate that code on every page isn't ideal at all.  That's the whole reason for building components in the first place, to not repeat the same code over and over.

Comment: It's sample, you can use a shared service instead, or check it in your master page

Comment: Gotcha, I'm already using that in the component.  My issue was simply that the page OnInitializedAsync fires before the parent component renders and redirects to the not found or login page.  Looks like it's expected behaviour and I need to rethink my approach.

Comment: What if `AuthenticationState.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true` yet the access token is invalid?  I would like to check for that case too but don't know how. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882574/how-can-i-prevent-or-globally-react-to-uncaught-accesstokennotavailableexception

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski IsAuthenticated should be false if the token expired. What do you mean by invalid ?

Comment: I have found that it is not always.  Assuming you are using local storage, you can simulate such a case by deleting the access token and refresh token out of local storage.  This can happen more naturally when the refresh token expires; I think its default is 24 hours, and this can happen when you leave your computer for more than a day and come back and refresh the page in the open browser.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski You mean the browser local storage ? If yes, never do that, it's a security issue as you cannot store the refresh token safely. The flow should be authorization code + PKCE

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with the internals AuthorizeViewWithPermissions, I can only venture to say that the LoginRedirect component should be exposed from the NotAuthorized property element, as NotAuthorized convey the dual meaning of having no permissions to access a resource, as well as not authenticated. You can be authenticated, but not authorized, and you can be authorized if you are authenticated only (this is the default), unless you define policies to be more specific about your requirements.

In terms of coding, please see how it is done in the default VS template:

```
 <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Again, your posted code is partial, and I can only guess... But I think that you have an issue with the design of your AuthorizeViewWithPermissions, related to what I was referring to above. Try to design it otherwise. Don't look for workaround, for this can prove fatal in the long run. Just try to change the design, based on understanding how the system works...

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'll update the original questions with more code, but I don't think that's the issue.  The redirecting works perfectly if I comment out the data call, or move it to the OnAfterRenderAsync method on the page.

The issue is that OnInitializedAsync is called before the components are loaded.  Debugging I hit the OnInitializedAsync on the first, and then it gets into the login redirect component, but by then the API call has already been started.

Comment: And using OnAfterRenderAsync causes a different issue, the page doesn't update with the data after it's retrieved.

Comment: I may have been over thinking this... using OnAfterRenderAsync and only getting data on first render, then calling StateHasChanged() works.  It just feels weird that in the examples and documentation they always use OnInitializedAsync, but then in the examples there's also no data calls that are secured.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the OnInitializedAsync gets called on the whole component tree before any rendering takes place, which is the root of the issue.  The redirect happens when the AuthorizeRouteView renders (BuildRenderTree), but by then the OnInitizalizedAsync has already fired on the page.

Comment: "but the issue is that the page OnInitializedAsync or OnParametersSetAsync fire before the LoginRedirect OnInitialized." This is expected behavior you should take into account when designing your components.

Comment: Thanks @enet, that was my feeling originally but wanted to validate I wasn't missing something.  You've been a big help the past couple weeks while I fumble through the first Blazor app.

Comment: You're welcome... but you know the way to thank folks here is to up-vote them...

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I found a tutorial online that recommends using a custom route view, however that would not allow me to perform any asynchronous calls to determine if the user was logged in.

So I found another solution that didn't require me to create a custom component or add code to every page.

Instead, I just added some code to my Main Layout and it works like a charm:

```html
@using System.Net
@layout TelerikLayout

@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;
@inject IIdentityService IdentityService;

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main" style="height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a onclick="@LogOut" target="_blank">Log Out</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4" style="flex: 1;">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await CheckLoginState();
    }

    private async Task CheckLoginState()
    {
        bool isloggedin = await IdentityService.IsLoggedIn();
        if (isloggedin == false && NavigationManager.Uri.Split("?").ToList().FirstOrDefault()?.EndsWith("/login") != true)
        {
            var returnUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).PathAndQuery);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?returnUrl={returnUrl}");
        }
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private async void LogOut()
    {
        await IdentityService.Logout();
        await CheckLoginState();
    }
}
```

I have not tested this solution in a production environment, but so far, it seems to be good.